# Woocommerce: get number of Variations in Product

Tags: function, woocommerce

I have this function to get the Regular Price for a woocommerce product. It works fine, but I need to add a line of code to also get the number of Variations in the Product.

```
function save_product_on_page_load() {
    if ( get_post_type() === "product" ){
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() ); 
        if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {

            echo $price = $product->get_price();

        }       
        if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

            echo [NUMBER OF VARIATIONS FOR THIS PRODUCT];

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `get_available_variations()` method, and then use PHP's `count()` function to get the number of variations. Here, I'm echoing the value on the single product page before the add to cart button.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'so58344618_variation_count' );
function so58344618_variation_count() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $count      = count( $variations );
        echo '<p>Number of variations: ' .$count. '</p>';
    }
}
```